# Is there a hook that runs for all read only buffers

Tags: hooks, whitespace, read-only-mode

I want to enable `show-trailing-whitespace` for editable file and disable `show-trailing-whitespace` for read only files. I've tried

```
(defun my/read-only-whitespace ()
  (setq-local show-trailing-whitespace (not buffer-read-only)))

(setq-default show-trailing-whitespace t)
(add-hook 'read-only-mode-hook #'my/read-only-whitespace)
```

But this only only seems to work if I enable `read-only-mode` manually. When I open a buffer that becomes read-only automatically (e.g. a read-only file) then the hook is not run.

Is there a hook that runs for all read-only buffers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want this to act in any buffer, not just a file-visiting buffer then `find-file-hook` is not appropriate. (You said "*all buffers*", but you also spoke of editable/non-editable "*files*".)

If you want it to work in all buffers then this is one solution:

```el
(defun my-show-trailing-ws ()
  "Show trailing whitespace in the current buffer, unless it is read-only."
  (setq-local show-trailing-whitespace (not buffer-read-only)))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-show-trailing-ws)
```

You can wrap that in a minor mode command, if you like.

Another possibility is to use an idle timer, but `post-command-hook` seems fine for what you're looking for.

As far as I know, there is no hook that corresponds to a change in `buffer-read-only`. However, if you use Emacs 26 or later then you can use function `add-variable-watcher` to turn on/off showing trailing whitespace whenever variable `buffer-read-only` is changed.

```el
(add-variable-watcher 'buffer-read-only 'foo) ; Add watcher `foo'

(defun foo (symbol newval operation where) ; 100% untested...
   "Show trailing whitespace in the current buffer, unless it is read-only."
   (when (and (eq symbol 'buffer-read-only)
              (memq operation '(set let))
              (eq where (current-buffer)))
     (setq-local show-trailing-whitespace (not newval))))
```

Comment: It seems a bit overkill to run this function after every command. Is their no simpler way?

Comment: @Moyamo Try it, then decide if you think it makes emacs sluggish. My bet is that you won't notice any slowdown or increased cpu usage due to this code. If you're worried, make sure that `my-show-trailing-ws` is compiled.

Comment: The variable watcher solution for Emacs 26 works well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find-file-hook` and check the read only status of the buffer:

```lisp
(defun my/read-only-whitespace ()
  (when buffer-read-only
    (setq-local show-trailing-whitespace (not buffer-read-only))))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my/read-only-whitespace)
```

Comment: As @Drew said, this won't work for special buffers like org-agenda buffers.

Comment: He's right about that. However, it wasn't clear to me that you wanted that generality. (Maybe it wasn't clear to you, either …)